# Disable admob ads after a click?

Tags: android, click, admob, adview

Hi All ~ Is that possible to disabled admob ads after clicked ?
I tried with this code but nothing happened, can anyone please help me out ? 
Thanks in advance

```
    final LinearLayout layout = ( LinearLayout )findViewById( R.id.adslayout ) ;
    final AdView adView = new AdView( this, AdSize.BANNER, "a11111111b9041" ) ;
    layout.addView( adView ) ;
    adView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE ) ;
    adView.loadAd( new AdRequest() ) ;

    adView.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
    { 
       public void onClick( View v ) 
      {
            layout.removeAllViews() ;
            adView.setVisibility( View.GONE ) ;
             ed.putBoolean( "adsClicked", true ) ;
             ed.commit() ;
      } // onClick() 
    }  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class implements AdListener, you can put your disable code into onDismissScreen(). This method is called when the user closes the advertisement and returns to your app.

For example:

```
public class Advertisement implements AdListener{

    // more code here

    @Override
    public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
        mainLayout.removeView(adView);
    }

    // more code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one undocumented (?) method for the AdView widget which is *stopLoading*.
I think that should do the job.

Simply hiding the widget does not stop it from keep requesting Ads.

Answer (score 0):

Override onAdLeftApplication and set a variable. Then you can skip loading ads depending on that variable

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);

interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
   @Override
   public void onAdLeftApplication(){
       user_has_clicked_ads = true;
   }
```

check documentation
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener.html#onAdLeftApplication()